# Uploading Files with Model Binding in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I came across this [Upload multiple files in MVC3 with model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127648/upload-multiple-files-in-mvc3-with-model-binding) which shows how to upload files with a model binding using MVC 3.  However, I am using MVC 4 and there is no such type `HttpPostedFileBase`.  I only have `HttpPostFileBaseModelBinding`.  Are these the same thing?

Ideally, I would like to be able to do this:

```
public List<AdjusterFile> eoFiles { get; set; }
```

But, it looks like I have to instead, do something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBaseModelBinder> eoFiles { get; set; }
```

How can I provide a simple property to both retrieve and send my files via my model?

Edit:

**Can I combine the following properties into one property to download and upload files?**

```
public List<AdjusterFile> 
         eoFilesDownstream { get; set; } // property for retrieving existing files
public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> 
         eoFilesUpstream { get; set; } // property for uploading new files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpPostedFileBase` is in `System.Web` namespace and don't depending of ASP>NET MVC version. Check references and `using` directives.

Comment: Thanks, I just added it and it works.  However, I want to not only upload files from this form, but also display files that have already been uploaded.  Can I do this from the same property, or must I create a separate property for retrieving the existing files and another property for uploading new files?

Comment: I recoomend you to use `return RedirectToAction()` after files uploading to prevent repeated upload in case of user refreshed page in browser.

Comment: I already am using `return RedirectToAction()` but I am asking how can I combine my two properties for retrieving the upload from the database and uploading the HttpPostedFileBase to the database?  What is the best practice?  Thanks.

Comment: You can use generic types, but it is not a great idea for this case :) In my projects I use different models for same cases.

Comment: Please tell me what you do recommend in this case.  Do you understand what I want to do?  I want to both retrieve existing files from the database, as well as upload new files via my form, both from my model which gets passed to and from my view.

Comment: I think you dont't need to pass **files** to view. You can pass any file identifier that can represent file and can be set as parameter for download action.

Comment: So, this still suggests that I have one property for my file identifiers (`Guid`) and another for the `HttpPostedFileBase`.  Right?  Thanks, again, for your help.